# como puedo crear una funcion que ponga un limite y verifique si son números

Tags: c, string

Quiero hacer una función para id para ponerle un limite de caracteres (en este caso son números)

> por ejemplo id:1234567890 así

y que solo tenga numero lo que hasta hora entiendo es que serian dos  uno para el limite es y otro para verificar que sean solo números pero mi profesora quiere que lo hagamos en uno solo como en la fecha y hora  ahi no puse todo el codigo por que es un poco largo
y algo un poco aparte si conocen de algún buen libro o canal de youtube sobre C

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<ctype.h>
typedef struct {
    int anio;
    int mes;
    int dia;
}fecha;
typedef struct {
  int hora;
  int minutos;
}hora;
typedef struct{   //Roitman Anddres Palacios Herdoiza
    int id;
    char mascota[20];     //especie
    fecha  fechaAlimentacion;
    hora horaAlimentacion;
    char decripcionAlimento[50]; //Croquetas,Carne,Pollo ,Pescado,etc
    float cantidad; //cantidad(kg)
    int estado;
}Alimentacion;
int registrar(Alimentacion*personal,int n);
void presentar(int i,Alimentacion*animales); 
int buscar (int id,Alimentacion*animales,int i);// declaracion o prototipo
void verAnimales(Alimentacion x);
int buscarx2(float cantidad,char *mascota,Alimentacion*animales,int n );
void actualizar(Alimentacion*animales,int i);

int main(){
    char op=' ',resp=' ',act=' ';
    int n=0,i=0,posicion=0;
    int id ;
    char mascota[20],decripcionAlimento[50];
    float cantidad=0.00;
        Alimentacion *animales=NULL;
    char mensaje[]="\nAnimales a alimentar\n[1] Registro  \n[2] Presentar Todos \n[3] Buscar por id\n[4] Buscar por mascota y cantidad de comida\n[5]Actualizar\n[6]Elimniar\n[7]ACERCA DEL CREADOR DEL PROGRAMA\n[o]Salir\n " ;
     do{
        printf("Cuantas mascotas van a ser aliemtadas: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);fflush(stdin);
     }while(n<=0);
     
     animales=(Alimentacion *)malloc(n*sizeof(Alimentacion)); //arreglo dinamico
     i=0;
     do{
        printf("%s",mensaje);
        scanf("%c",&op);fflush(stdin);
        switch(op){
            case '1':if(i<n){
                     i=registrar (animales ,i);
                }else{
                    printf("Ya no hay cupos para atencion");
                }
            break;
            case'2': presentar(i,animales);  break;
            case'3': printf("Ingrse la id a buscar: ");
                     scanf("%d",&id);fflush(stdin);
                     posicion=buscar(id,animales,i);
                     if(posicion!=-1){
                          printf("\nEl animal con id  %d es: ",id);
                          verAnimales(animales[posicion]); 
                     }else
                     printf("Animal  con cedula %d no se encuentra ",id);
                    
                              break;
            case'4':printf("Ingrese la especies y la cantidad de comiida:");          
                      scanf("%.2f %c",&cantidad,mascota);  
                      posicion=buscarx2(cantidad,mascota,animales,i);       
                      if(posicion!=-1){
                        printf("\nLos animales de especies %s y su cantidad de comida %.2f");
                        
                      } else{
                        printf("Estos animales no estan en la lista ");
                      }        
                               break;
           case'5': actualizar(animales,i);
                             break; 
            case'6': printf("Ingrese el id del animal");     
                    scanf("%d",&id);fflush(stdin);
                    posicion=buscar(id,animales,i); 
                    if(posicion!=1){
                           verAnimales(animales[posicion]);
                           printf("\nQuiere eliminar de la lista al animal a dar baja: ");
                           scanf("%c",&resp);fflush(stdin);
                          if(resp=='1'){
                               animales[posicion].estado=0;                         
                                printf("Animal %s eliminado ",animales[posicion].mascota);
                }
                }                             
                break; 
         }
     }while(op!='0');
      free(animales);
     return 0;
}

int registrar (Alimentacion*personal,int i){
    int dia=0, mes=0, anio=0,y=0;
    char x [ 20] ;
    //char*descripcionAlimento=(char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    printf("Id:  ");
    scanf("%d",&personal[i].id);fflush(stdin);
    //personal[i].id=leerNumero("\nid:");
    printf("Especie:  ");
    scanf("%s",personal[i].mascota);fflush(stdin);
    printf("fecha de hoy  ");    
    personal[i].fechaAlimentacion.dia=LeerEntero("\nDia:",1,30);
    personal[i].fechaAlimentacion.mes=LeerEntero("\nMes:",1,12);
    personal[i].fechaAlimentacion.anio=LeerEntero("\nAnio",2000,2022);
    printf("\nHora de la comida");
    personal[i].horaAlimentacion.hora=LeerEntero("\nHora: ",1,24);
    personal[i].horaAlimentacion.minutos=LeerEntero("\nMinutos: ",1,60);
    printf("Descripcion del alimento: ");
    gets(personal[i].decripcionAlimento);fflush(stdin);
    printf("Cantidad de alimento: ");
    //personal[i].cantidad= leerCantidad("\nKilos",30.00); 
    scanf("%f",&personal[i].cantidad);fflush(stdin);   
    personal[i].estado=1;i++;
    return i;
    }
```

Esta es la funcion que utilice para poner limites en las variables de hora  y fecha

```
int LeerEntero(char*msj,int limInf,int limSup){
       int x=0;
       do{
        printf("%s",msj);
        scanf("%i",&x);fflush(stdin);
       }while(x<limInf||x>limSup);
   return x;
   }
```

Comment: He leído la pregunta media docena de veces y todavía no me queda claro qué es lo que necesitas. En el título dices de validar letras y números y en la pregunta hablas de limitar el número de caracteres...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para que sea más clara

Comment: En si me trato de hacer una función que controle el numero de caracteres y que solo contenga números

Comment: No deberías depender de `fflush(stdin)`. [Su comportamiento con streams de entrada es indefinido](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18170435/13419694). Mejor usa `getchar` con el propósito de descartar el salto de línea que deja `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar que el usuario únicamente introduce números puedes leer la secuencia en modo texto y después comprobar que toda la secuencia contiene únicamente dígitos numéricos.

```
int leerSecuenciaNumerica(char *msj)
{
    char * entrada = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    int soloNumeros = 1;
    do
    {
        puts(msj);
        size_t lineSize = getline(&entrada, &len, stdin);

        soloNumeros = 1;
        for (size_t i=0; i<lineSize-1 && soloNumeros; i++)
        {
            printf("%c %d\n", entrada[i], (int)entrada[i]);
            soloNumeros = isdigit(entrada[i]);
        }

        if (!soloNumeros)
        {
            puts("ERROR: Solo se admiten digitos numericos\n");
        }
    } while (!soloNumeros);

    int salida;
    sscanf(entrada, "%d", &salida);

    free (entrada);

    return salida;
}
```

Algunas notas sobre la función:

- `getline` reserva memoria automáticamente según la va necesitando. Por eso necesitamos llamar a `free`
- `len` se usa para que `getline` sepa cual es la capacidad de `entrada` en todo momento. `lineSize` te dice el número de caracteres de la secuencia actual
- `getline` te devuelve también el salto de línea final, por eso en el bucle iteramos hasta `lineSize - 1`, para evitar dicho caracter

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor sería usar fgets para capturar el id como una cadena ya que ya puedes controlar el número de caracteres directamente.

Después con strtol comprobamos que sean todo números. Es una función similar a atoi pero con control de errores, por lo que podemos saber si algún carácter no es un número.

Resumen:

1. Leemos el id como una cadena con fgets a la vez que controlamos el número de caracteres.
2. Comprobamos con strtol que todos los caracteres introducidos son números

Dejo algunos comentarios por si quieres hacerlo con scanf.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_LONGITUD 10     //longitud máxima del id

int capturarId(int * id)
{
char cadena[MAX_LONGITUD];
// int longitud; // solo necesario para scanf
//Definimos un puntero temporal para comprobar que solo se han introducido numeros
char * ptmp = NULL;
    
    //scanf("%s\n",cadena); //se puede hacer con scanf pero puede dar problemas
    
    //guardamos en el array cadena el id
    fgets(cadena, MAX_LONGITUD, stdin);
    //como fgets captura también el salto de linea, lo quitamos
    if ((strlen(cadena) > 0) && (cadena[strlen(cadena) - 1] == '\n'))
    {
        cadena[strlen(cadena) - 1] = '\0';
    }

    /* 
    //SOLO ES NECESARIO SI USAMOS scanf ya que con fgets ya controlamos el tamaño
    printf("la cadena introducida es = %s\n",cadena );
    longitud= strlen(cadena);
    printf("longitud = %d\n",longitud);

    //comprobamos que la longitud es la adecuada y si no lo es, devolvemos -1
    if (longitud > MAX_LONGITUD)
    {
        printf("ERROR. La longitud máxima ha sido superada\n");
        return(-1);
    }
    */

    //si seguimos es que la longitud es la adecuada
    //ahora vamos a comprobar que solo se han introducido números

    //utilizamos strtol ya que es más completo que atoi
    (*id) = strtol(cadena,&ptmp,10);    //10 porque es base decimal

    // si el puntero es 0, significa que todo son números.
    // si el puntero es desigual a 0 significa que no todo son números.
    if (*ptmp != 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR. El id introducido no son números\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    // una vez hechas estas comprobaciones, seguiria el programa
    printf("El id es válido!!!\n");

    return 0;


}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//vamos a usar un entero para guardar el id.
//en caso de que el id fuera muy grande, se podria usar un int long long por ej.
int id;
int retorno; //para ver si todo ha ido bien
    retorno = capturarId(&id);
    // si todo ha ido bien, retorno será 0
    if (retorno == 0)
        printf("El id guardado es: %d\n",id);
    return 0;
}
```